# WinUI Using Merged Dictionary from a DLL

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, winui

I have this requirement where I need to access a resource dictionary defined in a DLL in my project as a merged dictionary. The whole project is setup as a C++/WinRT xaml hosted MFC application. And the required ResourceDictionary is a part of another dll.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
   <ResourceDictionary Source="PathToDict/CommonDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

As shown here in the Source property, CommonDictionary.xaml exists as part of another projects binary(dll) and I need to merge that file to my project by specifying the a path to it.
I've already tried something like this although this works only for WPF;

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myNameSpace;component/CommonDictionary.xaml"/>
```

And also tried this after adding a reference to the project;

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyNamespace/CommonDictionary.xaml"/>
```

None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

if your file in project directory, try to use

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///CommonDictionary.xaml"/>
```

Generally, you can open any Page.g.i.cs file and see any string with Uri define. For example:

```
global::System.Uri resourceLocator = new global::System.Uri("ms-appx:///View/Page.xaml");
```